# How to store a file in mongoDB collection?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, annotations

I am working on Web application which use MongoDB for storing. I have a requirement to store the file in MongoDB. But mongodb creates two different collections (i.e, fs.files and fs.chunks). Is it possible to store the file within the custom created collection.

**For Example :**

```
        @Document(collection = "client")    
        @Getter(value = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
        @Setter(value = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
        @NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
        @EqualsAndHashCode(of = "clientCode")
        public class Client {

            @Id
            private ClientId clientCode;

            private Set<ClientDocument> clientDocuments;
}
```

Here the **Client** is my collection and it has set of client documents.
I need to store the file in client collection, so that I can differentiate between the document for different clients.

Comment: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/183689081/storing-large-objects-and-files-in-mongodb

Comment: You can still use GridFS when you put the clientCode in the metadata.